# Использование подзапросов в Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Ошибка

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 18:0 Failed to recognize predicate 'select'. Failed rule: 'queryStatementExpression' in subquery source"

при выполнении:

```
select * from
(
with t as 
(
select ...
)

select a.*
from t as a
 join t as b on ...
)
```

Без начальной конструкции `select * from` работает нормально. В чем проблема?

P.S. Нужно для загрузки данных в `QlikView`.

Comment: Ошибка " Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 18:0 Failed to recognize predicate 'select'. Failed rule: 'queryStatementExpression' in subquery source" при выполнении:

select * from ( with t as ( select ... )

select a.* from t as a join t as b on ... )

Без начальной конструкции "select * from" работает нормально. В чем проблема?

P.S. Нужно для загрузки данных в QlikView.

Comment: так для чего здесь вообще нужна конструкция `select * from` в начале? И какая версия Hive?

Comment: Hue™ 3.9.0 . Вообще нужно, чтобы код дальше вставить в скрипт загрузки QlikView. В хью тестирую.